# Explanation for something in a Functional Analysis book by Kesavan

Tags: functional-analysis

My wife is reading "Functional Analysis and Applications" by Kesavan.  On page $140$, at the bottom it says "Let $\Omega$ be an open set, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, and $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that $-\Delta u+u=f$ in $\Omega$.  And let $x_0 \notin \operatorname{sing.supp}(f)$."

Here $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the closure of the test functions on $\Omega$ in $H^1(\Omega)=\{u\in L^2(\Omega)\mid\,D^\alpha u\in L^2(\Omega)\text{ for all } |\alpha|\leq 1\}$ and $\operatorname{sing.supp}(f)$ is the complement of the largest open set on which $f$ is $C^\infty$.  The norm on $H^1(\Omega)$ is 
$$
\| u\|=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 1}\|D^\alpha u\|_{_{L^2(\Omega)}}.
$$

Why does such $x_0$ exist?

Comment: If it doesn't then, by elliptic regularity, $u$ is smooth and a classical solution.

Comment: @Jose27 You could make your comment an answer.